# Cannot Display Json Object from Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So right now I'm testing a standard login page. If username and password is entered, some JSON data will be displayed onto the HTML page. When an alert window is used to display the data it works, but when I want to display it on the page, it looks like it doesn't work.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text"/>
<br />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        //collect userName and password entered by users
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        gogo(userName, password);
    });
});


function gogo(userName, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",

        url: "http:urlhere.com", //to server
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
            data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
            success: function () {

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#result').html('User: ' + data.return);
}
            }
        })
    }
```

I think this should work, but for some reason its not working. However like I mentioned, the ALERT window to show data.return is working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a debug point in your success method and check if `data` is being returned correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.message`?

Comment: hmmm I think that might be the problem... let me test.

Comment: There are 2 "success: function(data) {  }" calls? or is it a typo?

Comment: typo. sorry about that.

Comment: sorry. looks like it was a typo in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have A success callback and a function success that was never called

```
success: function () {
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       $('#result').html('User: ' + data.return);
    }
}
```

you need to correct it by removing the outer functions

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   $('#result').html('User: ' + data.return);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks.

I was wondering. Does document.ready work without the onclick function?

Comment: document ready is a delegate function that is automatically called when you browser completely render all the elements in the view, so what ever you adds in the document.ready will be called once your dom is ready and all elements are accessible.

Comment: now your question `document.ready work without the onclick function` is a wrong question. the right question is `will onclick function works without document.ready`, and the answer is no,

Comment: Because if you try to bind a click event outside this function `document.ready` with an element it will try to bind before the element is created and your click event will points to no where,

Comment: you need to study this http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: I see what you mean. But for the sake of my lack of HTML skills, could you explain if this thinking is correct?

document.ready will run the functions as soon as the html page is ready. However onclick function in document.ready will run the functions only when "clicked".

Is this thinking correct?

Comment: `document.ready` will not run the functions, `document.ready` will be run when the page is ready. and it will bind the event to the click of that element

Comment: so the functions won't run without onclick?

Or are u saying, that the functions will run in document.ready [even without onclick] once the page is ready.

Comment: I just want to try making a webpage without using onclick. So I want to only use document.ready with functions inside (similar to the code I wrote above but without onclick). Are you saying that won't work?

Comment: no you cannout do this because user will first add user/pass and then press button and you need to trigger the function when the user press button

Comment: if you call it directly the function will be called with empty username and password

Comment: Yes I understnad your concern. I was just wondering even if its empty, would document.ready run the functions if .click is removed.

Comment: yes.. it will run the function right away when the page is ready. try it with creating a function adding alert() into it and add the call the function in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

Correct you Ajax call .. success event of ajax!

```
function gogo(userName, password) {
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",

    url: "http:urlhere.com", //to server
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#result').html('User: ' + data.return);
     }
    })
}
```